# Why do earned badges haven't a action when I click them (Stack Exchange Android App)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

I earned some badges and can see this in "Your recent activity".
But when I click them nothing happens. Why you don't set a link to the following pages?

For example to this page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2/student?userid=4375900
or to this page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2/student

[image]

Comment: Yes! Take me to the post that earned me that badge.. or to the badge's page, showing attribution count and listing all the users that earned it... make *something* happen!

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Network activities that don't have an associated question will open their associated link in a browser view.